# applying jquery to single media queries

Tags: jquery, css, media-queries

I'm trying to add different values to the jquery based on below in relation to the media query.

**HTML**

```
<div id="content">
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$("html,body").animate({scrollTop: 360}, 1000);
```

**Desired Effect, something along the lines of this**

```
@media handheld, only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {

$("html,body").animate({scrollTop: 660}, 1000);

}

@media handheld, only screen and (max-width: 768px) {

$("html,body").animate({scrollTop: 260}, 1000);

}
```

What would be the most ideal way of doing this?

Comment: that cannot be done my friend. You have to use screen width and heigth to archive that. You cannot add javascript code to a stylesheet http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437786/how-to-get-web-page-size-browser-window-size-screen-size-in-a-cross-browser-wa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a commenter said, you can't use JS and CSS together like that. You could do this though:

```
var width = $(window).width(), scroll = 360;

if(width <= 1024){
    scroll = width > 768 ? 660 : 260;
    // if (width > 768) means width must be 769-1024 so scroll = 660.
    // else the width must be 768 or below so scroll = 260 
}

$("html, body").animate({scrollTop: scroll}, 1000);
```

Comment: Thats great, my crude code was the best way for me to describe what I was looking for. Thanks for your help, works a treat :)